# Any backbone.js books available?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been very excited with backbone.js recently, but all I can find was minimal tutorials on the web. Have been searching for a backbone.js book, but since it just recently came out, wasn't able to find any. Was hoping you guys know currently in production, perhaps a beta available somewhere?

Comment: why not this http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/?

Comment: This helped us quite a bit: http://recipeswithbackbone.com/

Comment: "A creative-commons book on Backbone.js for beginners and advanced users alike" - https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals

Comment: @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya: because the docs feels like reading Chinese; a beginner has absolutely no clue what anything in the docs mean.

Comment: Yea, if someone were to read the docs, i would suggest reading the underscore docs first, then backbone will make more sense.

Comment: `Developing Backbone.js Applications by Addy Osmani` - an amazing book  
http://goo.gl/kARp1

Comment: Written by some core Backbone.js contributors: http://bleedingedgepress.com/our-books/backbone-js/

Comment: Checkout [Backbone.js Cookbook](http://amzn.to/15OMxOX) by your most obedient servant. It contains over 80 practical recipes about Backbone.js.

Comment: I was a big fan of Hackr.IO when I was learning Backbone - http://hackr.io/tutorials/backbone-js

Comment: Useful practical book: Backbone.js Blueprints by Andrew Burgess
http://www.amazon.com/Backbone-js-Blueprints-Andrew-Burgess/dp/1783286997

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a prerelease eBook called [Backbone JS on Rails](http://workshops.thoughtbot.com/backbone-js-on-rails) by some people who are well-known within the Rails community. I haven't purchased access to it yet, but the Table of Contents looks good.

Recently released ["Developing Backbone.js Applications: Building Better JavaScript Applications" by Addy Osmani](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025344.do).

Comment: I bought it couple days back, too bad its just ToC right now.

Comment: One of the Backbone.js on Rails book authors here - we're actively developing the book content, and are at a little over 50 pages now.  The link Ben included above has a ToC where we've marked how far along each section is.  I'm happy to answer any questions about the direction/content!

Comment: I have checked the free example and it looks very focused in how to integrate BackboneJS with Rails. I think if you are looking forward to go deep in BackboneJS this is not the book. (apart for the too high price)

Comment: You can get Developing Backbone.js Applications for free here: http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

Answer (score 24):

I do not think Backbone is big enough to require a complete book on it. It is only 4 base JS classes. I would suggest you look for books on MVC and design patterns related to it. This is really the base. Maybe some guides on restful web apps and HTML.

The best book is to read the annoted source here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html

Answer (score 15):

As Julien said it might be too small to have its own book, but [JavaScript Web Applications](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018421) by Alex MacCaw might be useful. It has a chapter on Backbone as well as other frameworks and covers a lot of general topics that are likely to be relevant to anyone working with Backbone.

Its available as a beta ebook now.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a screencast that might be helpful, it comes with a pdf that's a bit like a book.

https://peepcode.com/products/backbone-js